# RecyclerView scroll listener's method onscolled calls automatically without scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, endlessscroll

While implementing pagination. I faced this issue. Without scrolling the onscrolled method continuously calling.
Please check my code below.

For reference, I'm using [Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews and RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView)

There is also one demo example [this](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e).

I'm requesting data from API. So I implemented volley. After setup, strange thing happened. OnScrolled method continuously calling without scrolling.
Below is my code.

```
    HomeFragment.java

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    tvNoDataFound = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_data_found);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    context = view.getContext();

    // Lookup the swipe container view
    swipeProjects = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeProjects);

    // Setup refresh listener which triggers new data loading
    swipeProjects.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Your code to refresh the list here.
            // Make sure you call swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false)
            // once the network request has completed successfully.
            getProjects(0,0);
        }
    });
    // Configure the refreshing colors
    swipeProjects.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    List<LatestProject> getLatest = getProjects(0,0);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {

        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

            Log.e("here scrolling","scrolling---"+page+"---"+totalItemsCount);

            // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
            // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
            List<LatestProject> getLatest = getProjects(totalItemsCount,page);
        }
    });
return view;
```

after get the response from server, I used below function to set adapter.

```
public List<LatestProject> returnProjects(List<LatestProject> list, int offset, int curSizes){

    if(offset!=0){
        int curSize = adapter.getItemCount();
        latestProjectsList.addAll(list);
        adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, list.size() - 1);
    }else{
        latestProjectsList = list;
        adapter = new ProjectListAdapter(list,getActivity(),HomeFragment.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    return list;
}
```

In above code my first API call has offset 0. I don't know what is the issue. Is it because of volley asynchronous request?

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

                if (!isLoading) {
                    if (linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == rowsArrayList.size() - 1) {
                        //bottom of list!
                        loadMore();
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Source  : JournalDev